# change text and path to diffrent color on hover of button

Tags: wpf, button, hover

I have a Button which contain path and text.like This

[image]

On hover of button it should change color like this
[image]

This is waht i have done yet
Xaml file

```
<Button  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource DashBordMenuButton}" >
            <StackPanel >
                <Path Name="DIcon1" Data="{StaticResource IconReporting}" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  ></Path>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" > DASHBORD</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  LineHeight="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Margin="0,20,0,0" Text="Minir All Servers,Clients and Activies"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

style

```
<Style x:Key="DashBordMenuButton" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,4" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF36D8E0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>


</Style>
```

On hover its works fine what i want.but by default  path icon also becomes black instead of white.how can i solve this 
Thnks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Path is Filled with button `Forground` color by below XAML

```
 Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"
```

So before your `style` triggers for `Hover` the `Forground` of your `Button` is Black by default. You can change it by adding a setter before your trigger starts ie. add a `setter` for `Forground` of your `Button` like below.

```
<Style x:Key="DashBordMenuButton" TargetType="Button">
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF36D8E0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,4" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF36D8E0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
      </Style>
```

Added a `setter` to `style`

```
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF36D8E0"></Setter>
```